# Page cache coherency

Tags: linux-kernel, cache

From what I understand, there are hardware-implemented techniques to keep the CPU L1 cache coherent with the data in RAM (when performing read/writes on a shared variable)

- every write will invalidate the corresponding entry in all CPU caches
- or, every write will update the corresponding entry on all other CPU caches

Is there a similar mechanism (software/hardware-wise) for maintaining consistency on the page cache? As far as I understand, the page cache is a write-back cache, meaning writes only show up in the cache, but only show up on disk later "asynchronously" (e.g. when the page gets evicted from the cache).

Answer (score 0):

system calls *sync* or *fsync* instruct disk driver to make the writes persisted but it does not guarantee. Also both the calls are blocking or synchronous.